# Laravel Guzzle not working yet curl does: error is curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Could anybody help me with an issue regarding Guzzle in Laravel?

I have this bit of code using curl which works.

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['userId' => $appUserId]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($content); // I get a response, response is good.
curl_close($ch);
```

I get a good old response with all the data I need. Simple and nice.

However, the company I work with uses Guzzle throughout the app, so when I use Guzzle as such.

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $res = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'userId' => $appUserId
        ],
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
        // I have tried every imaginable header.
    ]);

    $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
    echo $res->getBody();
    var_dump($result);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
    var_dump('error');
    $guzzleResult = $e->getResponse();
    var_dump($guzzleResult);
}
```

I get major errors for some reason.

This is error.

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#317 (6) {
  ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(12) "Unauthorized"
  ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  int(401)
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Host"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "127.0.0.1:8000"
    }
    ["Date"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Wed, 19 Aug 2020 13:39:56 GMT"
      [1]=>
      string(29) "Wed, 19 Aug 2020 13:39:56 GMT"
    }
    ["Connection"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "close"
    }
    ["X-Powered-By"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "PHP/7.3.6"
    }
    ["Cache-Control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "no-cache, private"
    }
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "application/json"
    }
    ["Set-Cookie"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(316) "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImlPSHczMXRUQ0ZZTUVpRkFPZ052UHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiS0UrYVdkR2ZETWhcL2FLVjRhSVZPM1VxYjVWb3ZoN2dTZlwvWFlNa2hXam1WNVo1NHo3Mk9aZXc5ZFlzYzhlTlNUIiwibWFjIjoiYThiYWVlYjRmOWJmMDgxOWJmZDQzYjg2YWFmZDdjMDFiYzg0ODk5N2FlZTk3ZmI0YjY5MzlmNzYzMGExMThlYSJ9; expires=Wed, 19-Aug-2020 15:39:56 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/"
      [1]=>
      string(331) "laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImpkK2ZtblU3MFpBN3hoSlJ1Wk5Nb2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVVYxeGtTV09ZZzVoMUcyXC8yaVI0XC9ZbWdYa0hQdkxQZ0xMamE1YzNaZ0NCTjJYbWJSUGl0MWMwRU9rczFUeHdQIiwibWFjIjoiNjJkMGVkYmI0ZDcwMTg4YmZmNjZmYjliYzFjOTI1ODRlN2I4ZTM1MjYyN2U0M2M0YzlmODk0YWVjYzRhNzAyOCJ9; expires=Wed, 19-Aug-2020 15:39:56 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly"
    }
  }
  ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(4) "Host"
    ["date"]=>
    string(4) "Date"
    ["connection"]=>
    string(10) "Connection"
    ["x-powered-by"]=>
    string(12) "X-Powered-By"
    ["cache-control"]=>
    string(13) "Cache-Control"
    ["content-type"]=>
    string(12) "Content-Type"
    ["set-cookie"]=>
    string(10) "Set-Cookie"
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#315 (7) {
    ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    resource(484) of type (stream)
    ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    int(49)
    ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

If I set the debug to true, I get this

> ErrorException: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in file C:\xampp-7\htdocs\website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 59

I have used Guzzle before and it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 5):

```
'debug' => fopen('php://stderr', 'w'),
```

this worked for me

```
$client->request('POST', $url, [
            'debug' => fopen('php://stderr', 'w'),
            'form_params' => [
                'userId' => $appUserId
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Could you please describe why this works?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing some `form_params` to guzzle, but you are also setting the content-type to `application/json` and your data is not in json format. Try with

```php
$res = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'form_params' => [
                'userId' => $appUserId 
            ],
            'headers' => [
               'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ], 
        ]);
```

Also, to make sure the response body is treated as a string, you should use `getContents()`

```php
$responseData = $res->getBody()->getContents();
$result = json_decode($responseData);
```

Comment: Hi @gbalduzzi, I have tried that, all variations of headers, even removed the headers. Alas same issue. So bizzare that curl works and not Guzzle.